# Angular type casting not working

Tags: angular, ionic2

Code:

```
<ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let item of items;">
    <ion-card>
        <div class="image_area">
        </div>
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title class="capitalize">
          {{item.English_name.toLowerCase()}}
        </ion-card-title>
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <h4>Rate</h4>
                    <P>{{ parseFloat(item.Rate).toFixed(2) }}</P>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <h4>MRP</h4>
                    <P>{{ parseFloat(item.MRP_rate).toFixed(2) }}</P>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
        <button ion-button full color="primary">Add to cart</button>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

Anyone can please tell me why parseFloat is not working How can I make it workable? I am using ngFor loop so doing parseFloat and toDixed in controller is bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.item = { Rate: 12.1233,MRP_rate: 52.12222}

    $scope.itemtoparse =  parseFloat($scope.item.rate).toFixed(2)
}
```

`{{itemtoparse}}` do this before you try submitting to interface

Do it within the controller

Comment: Do it within the controller

Comment: As far as I know, you should never do any calculations in this {{}}

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{ (item.Rate).toFixed(2) }}<br/>
{{ (item.MRP_rate).toFixed(2) }}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "John Doe";
 
 $scope.item = { Rate: 12.1233,MRP_rate: 52.12222}
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct but as per my understanding interpolation logic will same even in angular 1.0 or Angular 2.0. If it is different please correct me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't just call any function you want from within the template.

You can only call functions that are declared on the component.

So, 2 solutions:

1. Calculate the rate and MRP in the component like:

   ```
   items = items.map((i: any) => ({...i, parsed_rate: parseFloat(i.Rate).toFixed(2), parsed_MRP: parseFloat(i.MRP_rate).toFixed(2)}));
   ```

   And later use {{ item.parsed_rate }} and {{ item.parsed_MRP }} in the template.
2. Define a parse function in the component (you could also use a pipe) and call it from the template

   ```
   parseRateAndMRP(s: String) { return parseFloat(s).toFixed(2); }
   ```

   And later use {{ parseRateAndMRP(item.Rate) }} and {{ parseRateAndMRP(item.MRP_rate) }} in the template